# How do I create an intent to launch any e-mail app?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I have found various topics here and elsewhere on creating an intent for sending e-mail and that seems to be pretty straightforward. I'm looking for an intent to just launch any e-mail client the user might have.

Here is the code I've seen for sending an e-mail (**posted just for reference, this doesn't serve my needs as I don't want to send a new message**):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
i.setType("text/plain"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"}); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of the message"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Body of the message");
```

Here is the code I put together for specifically launching the Gmail client by package name:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
startActivity(intent);
```

The code above works but isn't flexible in that a user might not be using Gmail but the other built-in e-mail application or a 3rd party e-mail app. I'm looking for an intent that would bring up the chooser in this case so the user can decide which app to launch to read e-mail.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to accomplish
>   this?

There is no such `Intent` -- you can tell this by examining the manifest for the Email application.

The only thing you can do is build yourself a list of email clients you wish to link to and use the `PackageManager` code you show above for each.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this will be the way I have to go. You'd think this would be a common type of intent that would be included as part of the platform.

Comment: Can you tell me how to build myself a list of email clients and use packmanager with it?

Comment: @Bhargav: You are certainly welcome to ask a separate Stack Overflow question about this.

Comment: @CommonsWare done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635746/how-to-create-a-chooser-for-a-list-of-applications-using-package-manager

Answer (score 5):

Can a mailto URL be used in some fashion to accomplish this?
--Edit--
I was able to accomplish this using the following code sample:

```
mt = MailTo.parse("mailto:yourname@gmail.com");
sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mt.getTo()});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Enter a subject");
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send a Message:"));
```

Comment: This will send an email. This is not what the OP wanted. The OP said, in boldface, "I don't want to send a new message".

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be Intent.createChooser(); and let the user 
to choose the right application.

BTW The list could contain not only email applications

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach but this won't work in my situation because I don't want the user to have to choose every time.